# Notepad++ automated replace

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace hundreds of lines of text in notepad++.
e.g. Replace:

```
Deep-Mirkwood_Province
    Deep-Mirkwood
```

With:

```
Deep-Mirkwood_Province
    legion: Deep-Mirkwood
    Deep-Mirkwood
```

Basically i want to add the line "legion: x" below x_province. x is the name of the province in the line below it (In this case Deep-Mirkwood).
How can i do that in a automated way in notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using the `Replace...` method in Notepad++.

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog box.

Once the dialog box is open, you'll need enable the use of escape characters by clicking the radio button `Extended`, which is located under `Search Mode`.

From there, in the `Find What` box, you'll want to type `Deep-Mirkwood_Province\r\n\tDeep-Mirkwood` and in the `Replace with` box you'll want to type `Deep-Mirkwood_Province\r\n\tlegion: Deep-Mirkwood\r\n\tDeep-Mirkwood`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After **Ctrl-H** and selecting the **Replace** tab, set this:

```
Find what: ([\-\w]+)_Province([\r\n\s]+)\1
Replace with: \1\2legion: \1\2\1
```

and **Search Mode** is **Regular Expression**

Then **Replace All** should work.

.. and don't forget to look any basic info about regular expressions and especially this page aterwards:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: Seems to work. But instead of making it like this: "Anfalas_province", 
          it makes it like this: "Anfalas", 
          removing the "_province" after the region name at the top

Comment: My fault, I focused on the dynamic parts and missed the literal splinter. Replace with should be like this: \1_Province\2legion: \1\2\1